# HQL wildcards with elements/indices

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have an hibernate mapped entity that contains a HashMap.

If I want to find, say, an instance where the map contains a key/value pair like name:John I can write

`'name' in indices(attributes) AND 'John' in elements(attributes)`

How can I modify this HQL to allow me to use wildcards? I would like to find any instances where the name begins with 'J' for example

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the parameters in your query by using wildcards. For example if you are using Hibernate your query should be something like:

```
   getSession().createQuery('name' in indices(:index) AND 'John' in elements(:value))
   .setString("index","'%" + index + "%'")
   .setString("value","'%" + value+ "%'");
```